# Which editor is available to create html5 pages

Tags: html

I have an assignment to create an Html5 page.
someonr told me to use Dreamweaver but doesnot use html5.
which editor i should use?

Comment: You don't need any special editor to create html5. The newest version of Dreamweaver supports html5 syntax highlighting for new elements, but you can create html5 in old versions of Dreamweaver.

Comment: notepad, vi, textpad, BBEdit ...forces you to learn what you are doing instead of WYSIWYG

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much any editor you like, Dreamweaver included.